# Android Media Player returns NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, exception, nullpointerexception

I know there are similar questions around, but all the answers were specific to those applications. I am getting a nullpointerexception but can't understand the problem. It is a very long activity class so i couldn't share. Sorry if it is not a clear question but all I need is some hints or ideas, how can I find the cause of this exception. **LOGCAT:**

```
12-25 10:54:31.845: E/MediaPlayer(14465): error (1, -2147483648)
12-25 10:54:31.865: E/AndroidRuntime(14465): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-25 10:54:31.865: E/AndroidRuntime(14465): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sametenekeci.vmail/com.st.vmail.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-25 10:54:31.865: E/AndroidRuntime(14465):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2079)
12-25 10:54:31.865: E/AndroidRuntime(14465):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2104)
12-25 10:54:31.865: E/AndroidRuntime(14465):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:132)
12-25 10:54:31.865: E/AndroidRuntime(14465):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1157)
12-25 10:54:31.865: E/AndroidRuntime(14465):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-25 10:54:31.865: E/AndroidRuntime(14465):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-25 10:54:31.865: E/AndroidRuntime(14465):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4575)
12-25 10:54:31.865: E/AndroidRuntime(14465):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-25 10:54:31.865: E/AndroidRuntime(14465):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-25 10:54:31.865: E/AndroidRuntime(14465):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
12-25 10:54:31.865: E/AndroidRuntime(14465):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
12-25 10:54:31.865: E/AndroidRuntime(14465):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-25 10:54:31.865: E/AndroidRuntime(14465): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-25 10:54:31.865: E/AndroidRuntime(14465):    at com.sametenekeci.vmail.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:90)
12-25 10:54:31.865: E/AndroidRuntime(14465):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
12-25 10:54:31.865: E/AndroidRuntime(14465):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
12-25 10:54:31.865: E/AndroidRuntime(14465):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2033)
12-25 10:54:31.865: E/AndroidRuntime(14465):    ... 11 more
```

Thanks for help.

**ADDITION:
[MAINACTIVITY IS HERE](http://snipt.org/BFk6)**

Comment: What is line number 90 in MainActivity.java. It causing error.

Comment: Or even it's very hard to tell what error it is without your java code.

Comment: Post the code of your `MainActivity`.

Comment: @GrlsHu MainActivity: [http://snipt.org/BFk6](http://snipt.org/BFk6)

Comment: Can you point out the line 90 @sametenekeci

Comment: @innocentkiller is right. can you please tell us what is on line number 90 in MainActivity.java

Comment: Line 90: `mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {`

Answer (score 2):

Change it:

```
mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // Rest of Code
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

your line number `90` causes nullpointer exception,

```
line number 90: mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
```

and cause of `nullPointerException` is,you haven't initialized media player 1st:
//first initialize it

```
MediaPlayer mp= new MediaPlayer();
```

then
use it,as you want, like this:

```
mp= new MediaPlayer();
mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.entermail);
    mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
```

Answer (score 2):

MediaPlayer is a state machine - if you call its' methods in the wrong order, you get problems. There are also two ways to initialise player:

1. Using create() method - in our case:

   ```
   mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.entermail);
   ```

This line will initialise you player with the resource sound passed as an argument. If successful, prepare() will already have been called and must not be called again.

You're getting an error on this line:

```
mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
```

which indicates that mp is null. Check the result of create() before setting listener:

```
if (mp != null) {
    mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
    // rest of the code
}
else {
    Log.d("AUDIO", "MediaPlayer.create() failed. mp is null");
    // deal with it accordingly
}
```

In your case, check the file you're using in create(), and make sure that [(form the Docs)](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html):

> In this case, a "raw" resource is a file that the system does not try to parse in any particular way. However, the content of this resource should not be raw audio. It should be a properly encoded and formatted media file in one of the supported formats.

2. You can create MediaPlayer object with the constructor:

   ```
   mp = new MediaPlayer();
   ```

then remember to set data source and prepare:

```
    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), myUri);
    mediaPlayer.prepare();

    //when ready
    mediaPlayer.start();
```

Remember to catch exceptions on setDataSource. Also remember to call release() on MediaPlayer object when you're done with it.

By the way, after you set your listener, you call setAppState(), which in turn calls:

```
mp.reset();
mp.setDataSource();
mp.prepare();
mp.start();
```

So you might as well initialise your player with the second method, and set OnErrorListener to check if there are any errors.

[The guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html) also advises to call any long operations (such as prepare()) on a separate thread, as not to block UI thread. Please go through the guide and read about the states, it will help you realize what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

I know why ( maybe :) )
In the method **setAppState()** u call **mp.prepare()** in the try catch block then u call **mp.start()** outside that try catch. **mp.prepare()** may caused an exception.

Call **mp.start();** in the try catch block to ensure that mp has prepared successfully.

```
try {
    mp.prepare();
    mp.start();
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hello you can solve your problem by adding `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />     in your manifest`